# How to preserve the mutual arrangement of html <b> and <center> tags when lxml.html.fromstring is used

Tags: python, html, tags, lxml

The `lxml.html.fromstring` function parses the combination of html `<b>` and `<center>` tags in a strange way:

```
lxml.html.tostring(lxml.html.fromstring("<b><center>hello</center></b>"))
```

gives: `<div><b></b><center>hello</center></div>`.
Please notice that `<center>hello</center>` was moved out of `<b></b>` braces.

The question is how to preserve the layout and span of the pair of `<b>` tags the same as in the initial text?

FYI. If you swap the application of tags

```
lxml.html.tostring(lxml.html.fromstring("<center><b>hello</b></center>"))
```

you'll have the the correct result: `<center><b>hello</b></center>`

I use Python 2.7.9 and lxml 3.4.2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because your original code is not actually valid HTML.

`<center>` is a block-level element, and `<b>` is an inline element. Inline elements cannot contain block elements. lxml is doing its best to interpret the code as valid HTML.

Note also that `center` has been deprecated anyway since HTML4; you really shouldn't be using it.