# Difference in trees generated by html.fromstring() and etree.fromstring()

Tags: xpath, lxml

A bit confused about the effects of these two methods. Here's a simple string:

```
test = """
   <p> This is my head <h1>  this is my middle </h1> and this is my tail.</p>    
"""
```

We create two roots with this string:

```
from lxml import html, etree

root_e = etree.fromstring(test)
root_h = html.fromstring(test)
```

Let's see what the trees look like:

```
tree_e = etree.ElementTree(root_e)

for elem in root_e.iter():
   print(tree_e.getpath(elem))
```

Output is:

```
/p
/p/h1
```

which is what I would expect. However with:

```
tree_h = etree.ElementTree(root_h)

for elem in root_h.iter():
    print(tree_h.getpath(elem))
```

the output is now:

```
   /html/div
   /div/p
   /div/h1
```

which I didn't expect. And strange consequences follow. Various xpath expressions work the same in both trees, but others don't. For example

```
root_h.xpath('/html/div')[0].text_content()
```

outputs the whole string text (with a newline attached), although `test` has neither `html` nor `div` in it. On the other hand,

```
root_h.xpath('/html/div')[0].text
```

does nothing.

So why the differences, and when should you use one or the other?

Comment: Similar questions: https://stackoverflow.com/q/44976672/407651, https://stackoverflow.com/q/40302334/407651, https://stackoverflow.com/q/7180919/407651

Answer (score 1):

According to [lxml.html documentation](https://lxml.de/lxmlhtml.html):

> Since version 2.0, lxml comes with a dedicated Python package for
> dealing with HTML: lxml.html. It is based on lxml's HTML parser, but
> provides a special Element API for HTML elements, as well as a number
> of utilities for common HTML processing tasks.
>
> The main API is based on the lxml.etree API, and thus, on the ElementTree API.

---

```py
>>> etree.tostring(root_e)
b'<p> This is my head <h1>  this is my middle </h1> and this is my tail.</p>'
>>> html.tostring(root_h)
b'<div><p> This is my head </p><h1>  this is my middle </h1> and this is my tail.    \n</div>'
```

As you can see `html.fromstring` has added a `div` wrapper to our html fragment.

> [fromstring(string):](https://lxml.de/lxmlhtml.html#parsing-html)
> Returns document_fromstring or fragment_fromstring, based on whether the string looks like a full document, or just a fragment.

In this case the string looks like a fragment, so `fragment_fromstring` is used.

> [fragment_fromstring(string, create_parent=False):](https://lxml.de/lxmlhtml.html#parsing-html)
> Returns an HTML fragment from a string. The fragment must contain just a single element, unless create_parent is given; e.g.,
> `fragment_fromstring(string, create_parent='div')` will wrap the element
> in a `<div>`.

If we call `html.fragment_fromstring(test)`, it'll raise `lxml.etree.ParserError: Multiple elements found (p, h1)`. Apparently the `div` wrapper is added automatically to avoid that error.

---

> `root_h.xpath('/html/div')[0].text` does nothing.

```py
>>> help(type(root_h.xpath('/html/div')[0]).text)
Help on getset descriptor lxml.etree._Element.text:
text
    Text before the first subelement. This is either a string or
    the value None, if there was no text.
```

There is no text before the first subelement of `div`, so `text` is None.

---

> So why the differences, and when should you use one or the other?

I'm new to lxml and might be wrong, but my understanding after reading the quoted docs above is that they are basically the same, with `html` module being a little more customized for HTML parsing.

Comment: Not only was a `div` wrapper added to the fragment, the `</p>` end tag was moved (`h1` is not allowed as a child of `p`).